Como crear un array en el localstorage usando typescript
Estoy haciendo una To-Do app y quiero que persistan las tareas una vez creadas por eso necesito crear un array de objetos en el localstorage(quiero añadir otras funcionalidades),estoy usando angular y por consiguiente typescript, soy novato y hasta ahora solo he tocado javascript y tenía en mente usar una variable para poder acceder siempre que quiera a mi array del localstorage, de esta forma:
const arrayTareas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tareas")) || []

Como lo harían ustedes en typescript?

Todo código Javascript válido es automáticamente Typescript válido. TS es un superconjunto de JS

En este caso por lo menos no, me sale error: "No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo string | null a parametro de tipo string", entiendo que se debe a que puede ser que devuelva null y typescript no permite esto.

Para el compilador de TypeScript, el resultado puede no ser del tipo correcto, ya que en JavaScript JSON.parse() devuelve el tipo any, que para TypeScript es un tipo no recomendable de usar si se necesita acceder a las propiedades de los objetos en el array.
El código actual, al devolver el tipo any, no garantiza que el resultado sea un array.
Una idea para resolver esto es utilizar una interfaz o, simplificando, un type para una forma inicial de almacenar la información.
type Tarea = {
  id: number;
  descripcion: string;

};

Y al implementar los generic para reutilizar y permitir que la función acepte otros tipos de datos, el retorno de esta puede ser el tipo o null. En JSON.parse(datosGuardados) as T, el as está garantizando que el retorno sea del tipo especificado.
function obtenerDelLocalStorage<T>(clave: string): T | null {
  const datosGuardados = localStorage.getItem(clave);
  if (datosGuardados) {
       return JSON.parse(datosGuardados) as T;
   } else {
     return null;
    }
 }

function guardarEnLocalStorage<T>(clave: string, datos: T): void {
  localStorage.setItem(clave, JSON.stringify(datos));
}

arrayTareas contiene conjuntos de objetos del tipo Tarea. obtenerDelLocalStorage retorna este array de objetos Tarea.
let arrayTareas: Tarea[] = obtenerDelLocalStorage<Tarea[]>("tareas") || [];

El ejemplo
const nuevaTarea: Tarea = {
  id: 1,
  descripcion: "roronoa zoro"
};


arrayTareas.push(nuevaTarea);
guardarEnLocalStorage("tareas", arrayTareas);


Justo lo que me hacia falta, gracias boss!
